# Removing all event listeners in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript, flex3

How can I remove all event listeners on all components at once, especially when it is not known what listeners are attached to each component?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override mx.core.FlexSprite, which UIComponent inherets from, and generate an array of listeners created. Doug Mc Cune put up source code [here](http://dougmccune.com/blog/2008/02/21/monkey-patching-flexsprite-to-list-all-event-listeners-on-any-flex-component/).

His blog says: removeAllEventListeners() – removes all event listeners of all types. This completely wipes out all event listeners for the component all at once.

Let us know if this does the job!

Answer (score 1):

No!

You might be able to mock something up with [hasEventListener](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/events/EventDispatcher.html) and [willTrigger](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/events/EventDispatcher.html#willTrigger()).  But, there doesn't appear to be an obvious way to remove the event listeners without actually knowing the method name.

What do you want to do this for?

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue in Adobe JIRA for this task, please vote if you feel that it important for you

https://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/SDK-14127

Answer (score 0):

Elad Elrom has a post on his implementation to store event listener references, and be able to remove them all at once:

http://elromdesign.com/blog/2010/07/16/easy-way-to-store-event-listeners-reference-prevent-memory-leaks/