# AS3 listing references of an object

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Does anyone know if it's possible to list the references an object currently has in ActionScript3 (e.g. listeners, children etc)?

I'm trying to clear an object from memory ready for garbage collection but for some reason it's hanging around.

Thanks.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3405808/how-to-remove-all-event-listeners-in-flex) might be helpful to you.

Comment: I figure if there was a way to do this it would be trivial to prep objects for GC, which it's not unless you're paying attention from the start.

Comment: I think best way for You will be index main objects and add remove() function that manualy set references to null , remove arrays , sub objects , children , remove event listeners . Since i take care about GC , im using this class for index and remove listeners [ https://github.com/turbosqel/as3SupportLib/blob/master/as3SupportLib/src/turbosqel/events/SoftEventDispatcher.as ] and to each object add remove function that delete and remove references and instances .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you have flash builder, then profiling your app should give you pretty much what you need. Otherwise,you should be able to make a simple profiler of your own using flash.sampler.* api.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm working in Flash Pro. Did you have a particular sampler method in mind that would list the references? I've taken a look at the API docs but I can't see anything suitable.

Comment: there is no single api that's gets the job done. You can look at http://gskinner.com/blog/archives/2010/04/the_flash_sampl.html for an overview of the api. I don't have the code right now, but I'd try to post a crude implementation I did to find objects I knew were leaking out (may be by Monday!!)

Answer (score -1):

There is no way except to manually check every object, which obviously is not very feesible. Solution: learn2plan when you code, don't just slap stuff together. If you're writing code in such a way that you have no idea which objects are talking to which, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: I'm pretty saddened that people would give me drive-by downvotes on this. It's pretty simple, and even the person asking the question agreed with me. If you don't know how an object is tied to other objects in your program, especially to the point that it's stopping the GC from running, then you really need to reconsider whether or not programming is for you. Honestly, that's how bad that is. But please, keep giving drive-by downvotes. I'm not removing the answer because it's the truth.

Comment: It must be wonderful to sit your ivory tower and throw stones at people. Perhaps if Adobe wrote a GC that was reasonably competent this wouldn't be such an issue. While the first sentence may be an answer the second and your comment are down vote worthy.